# Paging 3 - Does Room drop pages even if maxSize is MAX_SIZE_UNBOUNDED?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 with Room and `RemoteMediator`. I haven't set a `maxSize` in the `PagingConfig` which means that we shouldn't drop pages no matter how far we scroll.

```
fun getSearchResults(query: String): Flow<PagingData<NewsArticle>> =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 50),
            remoteMediator = SearchNewsRemoteMediator(query, newsArticleDatabase, newsApi),
            pagingSourceFactory = { newsArticleDao.getSearchResultArticlesPaged(query) }
        ).flow
```

However, I noticed that Room still drops pages when I scroll far enough. I observed that in logcat via an `AdapterDataObserver`.

```
onItemRangeRemoved start: 100 count: 100 end: 199
```

**My question is: Is this expected behavior, or a bug, or some error on my side?** If it's expected behavior, what is the `maxSize` attribute for? I observed my data with a `maxSize` value set but it never removed any entries from the database.

Edit: I now also noticed that Room does **not** drop pages if we are looking at cached offline data. Why? I would expect it to behave exactly the same.

Comment: It should not drop items if `maxSize` is set to unbounded (the default), it's possible this is happening due to a bug with placeholder counts - could you file a bug and link your sample reproducing the issue here? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106&template=1096385

Comment: @dlam will do 

Comment: @FlorianWalther Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @MayurGajra unfortunately I don't remember and I don't have the link to the issue anymore 